# At the time of hudson build I have to remove file and rename another file

Tags: hudson

I have little knowledge using hudson can any one help me to resolve below problem.

In my project we are using 2 servers 1) Tomcat 2) WebSphere.

Tomcat is our local server used for development and WebSphere is production server. For WebSphere we use Hudson to create war file. We use common SVN Repository for our Local and Hudson. The problem is we have to use different web.xml files, in tomcat and websphere. 
For our local we created web.xml and for websphere created websphereWeb.xml.

When doing Hudson build we have to delete web.xml and rename websphereWeb.xml to web.xml.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You have to write a script (Bash, Batch, Ant, or any other language that Hudson can execute) to do your file manipulation.